# Absolute center dynamic number of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a backoffice where I can add cards to a spread and position them however I like using `top` and `left`. Then I have to present those spreads in my website.

My problem is that I would like to always center horizontally and vertically the cards in the spreads. The main problem is that the number of cards in each spread is variable, and each cards `top` and `left` are different depending on the users wishes.

I'm saving the `top` and `left` of each card in the database, and then I present them in the website.

Here is the fiddle to check out: https://jsfiddle.net/wajrga88/10/

Any help? Is what I'm asking even possible?

EDIT.: I've updated the fiddle with a more close to reality scenario.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kym60L9g/

Comment: if you are using position absolute , you have to use left or right. instead of px you can use %, so its auto adjust in any screen

Comment: Probably you can achieve your result using flexbox, as suggested by @bhv, but to further help, I would like to see a jpg with the final wanted result. Also, if you can, consider reducing your markup.

Comment: Please check my edit for a more updated and close to reality scenario fiddle

Comment: I could only offer a javascript solution to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only really possible with javascript since you need to calculate the bounding box for this.
Try this:

```js
//define dimensions of a deck - this is necessary for centering since the registration point is on the top-left corner of the deck
var deck_width = 54.6
var deck_height = 98.6

function setCardsPosition(target,positions){
 // calculate bounding box
 var minX = 9999
  var minY = 9999
  var maxX = -9999
  var maxY = -9999
  for(i=0;i<positions.length;i++){
    //this will find the most left (minX) most right (maxX) most up (minY) and most down (maxY) position of all the cards.
   minX = Math.min(minX,positions[i][0])
    minY = Math.min(minY,positions[i][1])
    maxX = Math.max(maxX,positions[i][0])
    maxY = Math.max(maxY,positions[i][1])
  }
  //calculate width&height of min-max coordinates - the bounding box (x=minX,y=minY,w=bounds_width,h=bounds_height)
  var bounds_width = maxX-minX
  var bounds_height = maxY-minY
  
  //get width&height of the container
  var target_width = target.clientWidth
  var target_height = target.clientHeight

  //get all 3 cards in container...you could create them dynamically aswell at this point
  var cards = target.getElementsByClassName('transparent_deck')
  for(i=0;i<positions.length;i++){
   //calculate cards position using the bounding box and the defined deck dimensions
    // target_width/2 -> center point of container
    // + positions[i][0] -> add raw position of current card
    // - minX -> move card so the most left card lies on the center of the container
    // - bounds_width/2 -> move card half the width of the bounding box of all cards
    // - deck_width/2 -> correct the cards position (due to the registration point is top-left for css absolute positions)
   var cardX = target_width/2 + positions[i][0] - minX - bounds_width/2 - deck_width/2
    var cardY = target_height/2 + positions[i][1] - minY - bounds_height/2 - deck_height/2
    //set position to style
    cards[i].style.left = cardX + 'px'
    cards[i].style.top = cardY + 'px'
  }
}

var positions1 = [[80,100],[150,140],[220,100]] // the positions of each card
setCardsPosition(document.getElementById('spread1'),positions1)
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #666666;
}
.transparent_deck{
 position: absolute;
 width: 54.6px;
 height: 98.6px;
 border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 border: solid 2px #ffffff;
}

.spread{
    height: 275px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 spread" id="spread1">
    <div class="transparent_deck" style="top: 100px; left: 80px;"></div>
    <div class="transparent_deck" style="top: 140px; left: 150px;"></div>
    <div class="transparent_deck" style="top: 100px; left: 220px;"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p class="spread_title">Title</p>
        <p class="spread_description">Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can set the positions via calling `setCardsPosition(CONTAINER_ELEMENT,POSITONS_ARRAY)`

Comment: Hey. I applied that code to my current situation but I'm afraid it doesn't work 100% :/ Here is the fiddle with my current scenario: https://jsfiddle.net/ddgtmj43/1/

Comment: that's because you used jquery even though its not included. Also the positions were mixed up a bit. https://jsfiddle.net/md47ncnm/

Comment: My mistake, the solution was. I forgot to take into account that in my backoffice the size of the cards were almost triple than what I had in the website, so I had to divide each top and left by 3 to make it proportionate. It works 100% now. Thanks :D (If possible, can you be more detailed in the comments in the code please? I would really like to understand every part of it so I can grow a little :p )